# How is it possible that the measurement uncertainty in Kalman Filter is less than 0?

Tags: numerical-methods, estimation, kalman

In Euan Sinclair's Option Trading, Pricing and Volatility Strategies and Techniques, it mentions that the true value of the price can be estimated via Kalman Filter:

$$S_\mathrm{new} = S + k (S_b − S),$$

where $S_\mathrm{new}$ denotes the new price, $S$ the estimation of the price, $S_b$ the new measurement and $k$ the Kalman gain.

The Kalman gain is defined as $k=\frac{e^2}{e^2 + m^2}$, where $m$ denotes the measurement uncertainty and $e$ the estimation uncertainty.

The estimation uncertainty is a function of trade size, $T$, i.e. $m = e \left( \frac{T_\mathrm{max}}{T} - 1\right)$.

When e is placed into Kalman Gain equation, we get:

$m =  ( \frac{1}{1+(\frac{T_\mathrm{max}}{T}-1)^2})$.

However, if we plot this equation and also the estimate uncertainty as a function of T:

[image]

It doesnt make sense that the estimation uncertainty goes below 0 since estimation uncertainty is the spread we want to quote in the market as a market maker. And Kalman gain tells us how much to care about the new measurement. As you can see Kalman gain is around 0.5 when uncertainty goes below zero which also does not make sense to me.

Is this a problem in the equation or am I just misunderstanding? Also if it is a problem, what is a better way of using Kalman filters in mean reversing market making?

Edit:

Also the graph should be measurement uncertainty vs T. I am sorry

Comment: I don't understand your question very well but, if the kalman filter gain is a function of $e$ and $e$ is a function of $T$ then $T$ needs to be involved in the kalman filter observation equation or system equation. I don't think you showed the full system that you're using for the kalman filter. If you did, then either $e$ can't be a function of $T$ or it can't be involved in the expression for the gain ?

Comment: I updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Also the graph should be measurement uncertainty vs T. I am sorry

Comment: Hi: I'm still not clear on where the equation for $m$ comes from but are you sure that $T$ can go past $T_{max}$ like you have it. Intuitively, I would think that $T$ can't go past $T_{max}$ since it's the max ?